How to write a test case for an HTTP stream route in Apache Camel Spring boot application?
I'm working with an Apache Camel route that consumes data via the stream:http component from an external HTTP service. The route processes the data and performs transformations like extracting JSON values
from("stream:http?httpUrl=https://myserver.com/stream?id=1234&httpHeaders=Authorization:Bearer%20My_Toekn,Accept:application/json&scanStream=true")
    .choice()
        .when(simple("${body} != null && ${body} != ''"))
            .log("Streaming id: ${body}")
        .otherwise()
            .log("Body is empty or null, skipping this message")
    .end();

I need to use docker test containers to write the test code
